# How to read binary data including zero bytes using BASH builtin read?

Tags: bash, read

I found bash ignores binary zero on input when reading using the read buildin command. Is there a way around that?

The task is reading from a pipe that delivers binary data chunks of 12 bytes at a time, i.e. 2 ints of 16 bit and 2 ints of 32 bit. Data rate is low, performance no issue. Since bash variables are C-style, the obvious `read -N 12 struct` does not work, bytes beyond a NUL are not accessible. So I figured I need to read the data byte by byte, using `read -N 1 byte`. Problems easy to fix are escapes (requires `-r`), and UTF multi-byte character coding (`export LC_ALL=C`). The problem I'm so far unable to solve is to deal with zero bytes. I thought they'd show up as empty variable `byte`, but in fact `read -r -N 1 byte` does not return at all upon zero (ignores zeros) but returns with the next following non-zero byte in the data stream.

This is what I was attempting to do, which, as long as no zero comes in, works without flaws:

```
export LC_ALL=C

while true;
  do
     for ((index = 0; index < 12; index++))
       do
          read -r -N 1 byte
          if [ -n "${byte}" ]; then
               struct[${index}]=$(echo -n "${byte}" | od -An -td1)
             else
               struct[${index}]=0
            fi
       done
... # some arithmetics reconstructing the four bitfields and processing them
  done < pipe
```

It turns out the `else` branch in the `if` is never taken. A data chunk of 12 bytes that includes a zero does not make the `for` loop run 12 times, instead it awaits more data to fill the `struct` array. I demonstrated the behaviour by feeding the pipe 12 bytes using the command

```
echo -en "ABCDE\tGH\0JKL" > pipe
```

Since it is so easy to fool oneself with this, I verified the sending of zeros with

```
~# mkfifo pipe
~# od -An -td1 <pipe &
[1] 25512
~# echo -en "ABCDE\tGH\0JKL" > pipe
~#    65   66   67   68   69    9   71   72    0   74   75   76

[1]+  Done                    od -An -td1 < /root/pipe
```

Is there a way to change this behaviour of bash? Or how else can the zero bytes be read?

Comment: Bash simply can't store NUL bytes in variables. You may want to look to other languages.

Comment: AFAIK, zsh is the only shell that can store 0 bytes in its variables. ksh93 has some helper features to help you base64 encode/decode data.

Comment: I do not need the NUL byte stored in a variable. As I pointed out, bash uses C-style strings, so in a sense, *every* variable contains a NUL byte. That's why I expect to receive an empty string from the read builtin. So all I need is that the read builtin **returns** on *every* byte, not non-zero ones only.

Comment: Related: [bash: read: how to capture '\n' (newline) character?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/383197). See also [Fastest way to determine if shebang is present](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/406939)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bash` variables can't store NUL bytes (only `zsh` does, though see also `ksh93`'s `printf %B` and `typeset -b` using base64 encoding). Its `read` builtin will also skip NUL bytes in input.

However, here, you could use:

```
LC_ALL=C IFS= read -rd '' -n1 c
```

That is read up to one byte off a NUL-delimited record. So if `$c` is empty,  that means either EOF (but then `read`'s exit status would be non-zero) or a NUL byte was read.

For both, you can get the numeric value of that byte with:

```
LC_ALL=C printf -v value %d "'$c"
```

So:

```
while
  IFS= LC_ALL=C read -rd '' -n1 c &&
    LC_ALL=C printf -v value %d "'$c"
do
  echo "Got byte with value $value"
done
```

Would read the input one byte at a time until EOF and support NUL bytes.

Or you could always do:

```
value=$(dd bs=1 count=1 2> /dev/null | od -An -vtu1)
```

Or with some `od` implementations:

```
value=$(od -N1 -An -vtu1)
```

Though that implies forking extra processes and run external executables (and if stdin is a terminal device, that will not put it out of `icanon` mode like `read` does).

Comment: Wow. Using ```-n```, rather than ```-N``` as the read builtin argument indeed nailed it. I had not tried ```-n``` because ```-N``` seemed indeed so much better suited to my purpose. I had tried ```-d ''```, though, without any effect, which is understandable given that the specs of ```-N``` clearly state that no delimiters are observed. Now, with ```-n``` I do have to care about delimiters, but that's easy (as between the lines you point out too). Thanks a lot!

Comment: I take it you suggest using ```printf```` instead of ```od``` because it's a builtin and therefore should be faster, as no new process needs to be forked?